# TCPDF MySQL Labels

Tags: php, mysql, tcpdf

Has anybody had luck creating labels (Either 30 to a page Avery 5160 or 10 to a page Avery 5163) with TCPDF?  I've found a few plugins, but I have not been able to implement them successfully.  I was going to start trying to adjust the 'multicell' example that they include in the distribution package, but I didn't know how to make it loop to print out all the labels that will output from the database.

My original plan was to use FPDF, as I've had experience with that before, but using their Label plugin, I can't change the font size of certain rows of the label.

My ultimate goal is to have Large Text on the first line of the label, and smaller text for the remaining lines of the label ... All made dynamically with PHP and MySQL.

Thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: FPDF would be a good choice along with the user supplied script for labels. It's a pretty simple piece of code and it should be pretty easy to modify fonts to suit your needs.

Comment: Unfortunately, using the Labels script, the font size cant be different for the various lines of the text.  That's important to me.  I'm just now starting to look at multicell and trying to figure out how to get the cells to be the appropriate size.  It's tricky!

Comment: It can't be out of the box but with the basic framework already there for you it shouldn't be too hard to tweak it.